# How to avoid max_allowed_pocket error while run my application on server?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have got error about need to increase max_allowed_pocket. Yes, I increased up to 1048576 but it throws the same error after 1 or 2 days. If restart my server its working temporarily, I couldn't restart the server again and again.

Comment: how u r set the value ? plz share the code?

Comment: I set the value max_allowed_pocket=1048576  in my-small.conf, my-medium.conf, my-large.conf and my-huge.conf files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to set below property in my.ini configuration,

[image]

or by executing following each time when you make a connection

```
set global max_allowed_packet=16777216;
```

Note:
also u can find that in below location,

```
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6
```

myself also got same error,after changing this property working fine.please Let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: yea sure I will check and revert back to you

Comment: I have to change only m.ini or need to change my-small.conf, my-medium.conf, my-large.conf and my-huge.conf files ?

Comment: only that file is enough to change.

Comment: till now i'm also not getting this error after changed in this property :)

Comment: in my file doesn't have anything I have an insert the max_allowed_pocket

Answer (score 0):

Before restarting the mysql server or extracting a database dump run given below mysql queries.

```
set global max_allowed_packet=1000000000; 
set global net_buffer_length=1000000;
```

EDIT : 

You can increase the performance by updating given below properties in my.ini file.

```
key_buffer_size = 128M 30% of your memory (Max 4GB)
max_allowed_packet = 5M
table_open_cache = 256
sort_buffer_size = 10M
read_buffer_size = 20M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 10M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
thread_cache_size = 8
query_cache_size= 30M
thread_concurrency = 8
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 256
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 5G  to 50% - 70% of your ram.
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 1G to to 10% of ram
innodb_log_buffer_size = 1G
innodb_log_file_size = 1G (Max 4GB) larger the file recovery slow. 
innodb_file_per_table = 1
```

Comment: after executes, the above query value has changed after restart the mysql server

Comment: For better performances change the given properties in my.ini file.